# Validating Today's Day of Week

Tags: jquery, postgresql

I am using the query below to check if today is Friday but it keeps returning False. Can someone help?

```
select case when to_char(now(), 'Day') = 'Friday' then 'True' else 'False'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about grabbing the day of the week in integer form instead:

```
SELECT case when extract('dow' from now()) = 5 THEN true else false end;
```

0 is Sunday, which makes 5 Friday.

Answer (score 1):

The output of to_char is padded to the length of the longest day name.

```
select trim(to_char(now(), 'Day'))='Friday';
```